# Is it correct to say "She cut her hair off the wheels"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

[image]

A girl with long hair got her hair tangled in the wheel of a toy car and she used scissors to cut her hair at the point where the hair contacts with the wheel to make it free.

Is it correct to say "**She cut her hair off the wheels**"?

Comment: Close, but I feel like "She cut her hair **away from** the wheels" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because having cut her hair, there was still hair on the wheel of the toy car.

She cut the toy out of her hair. Or she cut her hair to free the toy car's wheel.

Comment: How about "She cut her hair from where it got tangled." OR "She set her hair free from where it got tangled."?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: What does it mean by saying "**cut the toy out of her hair**"? The toy is so hard for me to cut, she can only cut the hair that wrapped around the wheel to remove the whole toy car. After that, she can use her hand to pick the hair in the wheel out.

Comment: @Tom - if you cut something out of your hair, you remove that thing from your hair by cutting some of your hair. If you are injured, a doctor in a hospital may have to cut you out of your clothes; the clothes get cut, not you.